# Excel VBA - Exception: Permission denied Error 70

Tags: vba, file, exception

Apparentely this piece of code causes trouble when another application is writing data into the data.txt file and VBA tries to read it.

Is there a way to ignore these exception or better yet to wait until the file is free to access and then continue executing the code?

```
fileName = "C:\TEXT\data.txt"
fileNo = FreeFile 'Get first free file number

Open fileName For Input As #fileNo
Do While Not EOF(fileNo)
   Line Input #fileNo, textRow
   jsonText = textData & textRow
Loop
Close #fileNo
```

Comment: Are the other processes which lock the file short-lived?  How long do you want to wait?

Comment: You wait. You're the programmer, go into a loop until successful.

Comment: @TimWilliams It is short-lived. It should be prolly a few milisoconds.

Comment: @Noodles I am not the programmer, if I was I would not be asking here.. I don't know how to make a loop in VBA, that's the problem..

Comment: This is a site for programmers. Turn on `on error resume next` so your code handles errors. After trying to open the file if unsuccessful do a `application.wait time` inside a `Do ... Loop` then `Exit Do` when successful. See Help.

Comment: @Noodles Where should I put the `on error resume next`? Right after what, `Open fileName For Input As #fileNo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this but I am not sure if it is 100% reliable:

```
Dim continue As Boolean

fileName = "C:\TEXT\data.txt"
fileNo = FreeFile 'Get first free file number

continue = True

Do While continue
On Error Resume Next
Open fileName For Input As #fileNo
If Err Then
continue = True
Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
Else
Do While Not EOF(fileNo)
   Line Input #fileNo, textRow
   jsonText = textData & textRow
Loop
Close #fileNo
continue = False
End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I mean.

```
fileName = "C:\TEXT\data.txt"
fileNo = FreeFile 'Get first free file number

On Error Resume Next
Do
    Open fileName For Input As #fileNo
    If err.number = 0 then 
        Exit Do
    Else
        Err.clear
    End If
Loop
On Error Goto 0

Do While Not EOF(fileNo)
   Line Input #fileNo, textRow
   jsonText = textData & textRow
Loop
Close #fileNo
```

Comment: Tnx for the answer. However I already came up with mine and it seems to work fine, so I guess I will stick with that.